# C# Анимация фигуры. Передвижение по Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация

Здравствуйте! Есть задача по анимации фигуры с изменением координат. Есть класс, в котором описана моя кастомная фигура, состоящая из двух объектов geometry. У нее есть свойство "начальная точка" и метод, который возвращает эту фигуру как объект Path. Надо как-то добавить анимацию, чтобы фигура двигалась по экрану и координаты созданного экземпляра класса этой фигуры соответственно менялись. Есть идея менять координаты и перерисовать фигуру, при этом удалив старую, но как найти старую фигуру, если исходных может быть несколько?
Если кратко, весь вопрос в том, как анимировать мою кастомную фигуру, чтобы, изменяя свое положение, ее свойства (координаты) тоже менялись?
Например есть класс Figure

```
public class Figure
{
public Figure(Point startPoint)
{
StartPoint = startPoint
}
public Point StartPoint {get; set;}
public Path CreateFigure()
{
//создание каких-либо примитивов и их передача в CombinedGeometry и path.Data
return path;
}
public Path Move()//движение фигуры по горизонтали
{
StartPoint.X += 1;
}
```

В классе MainWindow есть метод движения фигуры

```
public void MoveFigure()
{
Figure figure = new Figure(new Point (1,1));
Path path = figure.CreateFigure();
canvas.Children.Add(path);
//как дальше применяя метод Move показать, что фигура движется?
}
```

Comment: Через `Canvas.SetTop()`/`Canvas.SetLeft()` меняйте координаты фигуры. Что не получается?

Comment: «перерисовать фигуру, при этом удалив старую» — что? Вы случайно WPF не перепутали с MFC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно действительно, как говорят в комментариях, использовать методы
`Canvas.SetTop()`/`Canvas.SetLeft()`.

Тогда вам нужно добавить в метод `CreateFigure()` явную установку расположения фигуры на холсте

```
Canvas.SetLeft(path, 0);
```

Дальше - анимация.

Наверное самый простой (ну хорошо, не простой а `короткий`) путь достижения цели использовать анимацию на основе кадра. И, нет, конечно, это далеко не единственный вариант. Можно использовать таймер и точно так-же двигать фигуру. Или, если траектория движения заранее известна и довольно простая, то вы можете использовать анимацию на основе заданного пути. Выбирайте то, что больше по душе.

Но вернемся к первому способу

Все что здесь нужно - подписаться на событие `CompositionTarget.Rendering`

```
CompositionTarget.Rendering += CompositionTarget_Rendering
```

и затем правильно его обработать:

```
foreach(var x in canvas.Children.OfType<Path>())
{
    var left = Canvas.GetLeft(x);
    Canvas.SetLeft(x, left  + 1);
}
```

В действительности вам нужно реализовать более сложную логику (например, изменение движения фигуры при достижении видимой части холста). Но это уже совсем другая история, которая к данному вопросу непосредственного отношения не имеет.

[image: Гифка с результатом для демонстрации]

Описание фигуры из примера

```
Point secondPoint = new Point(StartPoint.X + 5, StartPoint.Y + 5);
Size size = new Size(10, 10);
CombinedGeometry cg = new CombinedGeometry();
cg.Geometry1 = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(StartPoint, size));
cg.Geometry2 = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(secondPoint, size));
cg.GeometryCombineMode = GeometryCombineMode.Xor;
```

---

Ваш вариант с удалением старой фигуры и отображением новой тоже имеет право на существование. Код будет аналогичным за исключением того, что не будет манипуляций со свойствами `Canvas.Left`/`CanvasTop`

Для начала исправьте метод `Move` в классе `Figure` в текущем варианте смысла он не имеет

```
public void MoveFigure()
{
    StartPoint = new Point(StartPoint.X + 1, StartPoint.Y);
}
```

Затем создайте список фигур и отобразите на холсте. При перерисовке очистите холст, передвиньте фигуры путем вызова `Move` и отрисуйте их заново

```
canvas.Children.Clear();
foreach (Figure figure in figures)
{
    figure.MoveFigure();
    canvas.Children.Add(figure.CreateFigure());
}
```